# Logging out other users from the command line

Tags: command-line, users

Sometimes when there are too many users logged in it can cause my computer to become very slow and laggy due to low amount of available RAM. I would like to be able to quickly log out the other users from the command line instead of manually switching into each user and logging them out.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

this is one answer

```
who -u
```

that give you the PID

Then you can kill the user session.

```
kill "pid"
```

Comment: This works but it has some strange side effects.

Comment: @DoR ...which are..?

Comment: @Oli Such as GDM restarting, and trying to switch to a user that I killed not working.

Comment: @AlvinRow If you execute `ps auxf` then you notice (left-most column has effective username) that this method doesn't kill all the processes which are executed by the current user (so *probably* you aren't logged out). The method of @precise seems to attend to this problem, though I don't feel comfortable with sending `SIGKILL`.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't something like with `shutdown` so it can give warning (allowing work to be saved) before forcibly logging out. That would optionally just switch to the login as if changing sessions, leaving the user session running in the background.

Comment: @pbhj about notifications, consider to see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/967130/970554

Answer (score 51):

You may use `who` to check which users are logged in:

```
who
```

You can log-out the user by sending the `KILL` signal to the user-process with:

```
sudo pkill -KILL -u <username>
```

(which is same as `sudo pkill -9 -u <username>`)

example:

```
sudo pkill -9 -u guest-2Rw4Lq
```

(to kill a guest session user named `guest-2Rw4Lq`)

**Note** (kudos to pbhj): If you get locked in a console, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to the GUI.

Comment: This worked best for me. Simply running `kill "pid"` left a ton of processes by the user still running, where this killed them all.

Comment: Why `SIGKILL` and not the default `SIGTERM` ? The `SIGKILL` isn't healthy..

Comment: `sudo pkill -KILL -u <username>` for me switched me to the first console session; I thought it killed my current session but ctrl+alt+F7 brought me back to the current graphical session.

Comment: -1: This command somehow triggered a higher priority process that never died, I had to restart the machine to kick the user.

Answer (score 8):

```
who -u


> adam     ttys000  Aug  4 09:22   .       91228
```

then

```
sudo kill 'PID number'
sudo kill 91228
```

PID (process ID) is the four or five digit number at the end of the user readout (91228)