# How to logout another user on 17.10?

Tags: xorg, restart, 17.10

In recent versions of Ubuntu, if one of my kids had locked the screen instead of logging out of their account, I could run this command to restart X and get to the login screen:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

But in 17.10, this command now results in this error message:

```
Job for lightdm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

What is the equivalent command in 17.10?

Comment: 17.10 used `gdm` instead of `lightdm`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

17.10 ditched lightdm and started using gdm

The equivalent to your command would be...

```
sudo service gdm restart
```

But ...

```
sudo pkill -9 -u {user}
```

would be correct for any Linux system. Users currently present can be shown with the `w` (/`who`) command.

But do be careful. I myself would get very angry if someone killed my session when I am not allowed to save my work in progress.

This would send a message to all systems:

```
notify-send "Ahum!"
```

It will disappear by itself.

```
zenity --info --text="Time to go to bed"
```

would show a popup that needs to be confirmed.

After that you can kill the session ;)

Comment: In a text-only environment you might want to use `wall message` to notify users.